# how do i get amount of datagram queued in a unix domain socket

Tags: linux, sockets, unix, datagram

I need to get the amount of datagrams queued/pending in a unix datagram socket and yet to be received. I see that max_dgram_qlen gives what is the maximum of datagrams that can be queued in the receive buffer after which it will be blocked. 
But, is there a way to how much datagrams is already queued for unix datagram socket via some socket options or via reading some linux files. Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Note that any value you obtain may already be wrong/out-of-date by the time you actually get a chance to do anything with the value.  You might be better off coming up with a design that doesn't try to depend on that information.

Answer (score 1):

read `/proc/net/udp`

From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/proc):

> /proc/net/udp
>
> Holds a dump of the UDP socket table. Much of the information is not of use apart from debugging. The "sl" value is the kernel hash
>   slot for the socket, the "local_address" is the local address and port
>   number pair. The "rem_address" is the remote address and port number
>   pair (if connected). "St" is the internal status of the socket. **The
>   "tx_queue" and "rx_queue" are the outgoing and incoming data queue** in
>   terms of kernel memory usage. The "tr", "tm->when", and "rexmits"
>   fields are not used by UDP. The "uid" field holds the effective UID of
>   the creator of the socket. The format is:
>
> ```
> sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr rexmits  tm->when uid
> 1: 01642C89:0201 0C642C89:03FF 01 00000000:00000001 01:000071BA 00000000 0
> 1: 00000000:0801 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 6F000100 0
> 1: 00000000:0201 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000 0
> ```